# External php file is not returning multiple checkbox data to my E-mail

Tags: php

The html code of the data I am trying to receive:

```
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-         width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; ">
<label for="first_name">First Name*</label>
</td>
<td valign="top" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; ">
<input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top" "="" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; ">
<label for="last_name">Last Name*</label>
</td>
<td valign="top" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; ">
<input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; ">
<label for="email">Email Address*</label>
</td>
<td valign="top" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; ">
<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; ">
<label for="service">Services required*</label>
</td>
<td valign="top" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; ">
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="CMS-Design">CMS Design&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="E-commerce">E-commerce<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Logo-design">Logo design&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Photo-gallery">Photo gallery
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; ">
<label for="comments">Comments *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; ">
<textarea name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; ">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>&nbsp;
</form>
```

And then the PHP part of the code:

```
// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "me@mail.com";
$email_subject = "Contact us";


function died($error) {
// your error code can go here
echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
echo $error."<br /><br />";
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
!isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['service']) ||
!isset($_POST['comments'])) {
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.'); 
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$service = $_POST['service']; // not required
$service[0] = $_POST['service[0]']; // not required
$service[1] = $_POST['service[1]']; // not required
$service[2] = $_POST['service[2]']; // not required
$service[3] = $_POST['service[3]']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Services: ".clean_string($service)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!--success html-->

Thank you. Someone will contact you very soon.<br><a             href="http://originwebdesigners.com/contact-us.html">Go back</a>

<?php
}
?>
```

Now my problem is, in the data I receive, I only see this for services:
services: array

Instead of:
services: CMS Design, Logo Design, etc

What am I doing wrong?
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: When you use brackets in the name for an html form element, you're creating a collection that will be passed back to the server, so by calling $_POST['service'] you're actually returning an array to the service variable, var_dump that and you should find your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your code

```
$service = $_POST['service']; 
// $service will be an array now containing all the checked services

$service[0] = $_POST['service[0]']; // not required
$service[1] = $_POST['service[1]']; // not required
$service[2] = $_POST['service[2]']; // not required
$service[3] = $_POST['service[3]']; // not required
// Will overwrite above $service-array with non-existet data, to retrieve
// a single value out of service you should use $_POST['service'][0] and
// not $_POST['service[0]']; 
// Because you already stored the services into $service above four lines
// are obsolete

$email_message .= "Services: ".clean_string($service)."\n";
// Converting an array to a string will end up with "Array" use
$email_message .= "Services: ".clean_string(implode(', ', $service))."\n";
// to rewrite it to a comma-seperated string
```

Comment: This has solved the problem. Thank you so much. I am still learning PHP. So, input like yours, is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`$service` is not a string, it is an array. Therefore, you will need to loop over the array to add each service to the `$email_message` string. something like a `foreach` loop would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$service=implode(',' ,$_POST['service']);
```

you ll get a string of services seperated with comma. u can send this string to email

Answer (score 0):

Use this form

```
$service[0] = $_POST['service'][0];
```